# how to use the SPSS software from data entry to analysis

Tags: spss

I am doing my dissertation paper, I adopted 4 different questionnaires and I have collected my data. 
I am using the SPSS software to analyse my data but the problem is I have little knowledge about the software. 
Please help me, how do I enter my data onto SPSS and how to analyse it ? 
Do I enter the data from the 4 questionnaires altogether at the same time or  should I enter each questionnaire data separately ? 
I have tried to enter data from one questionnaire alone but then how would I analyse or join it to the other 3 questionnaires for analysis ?

Comment: What format is your data in now? Did you ask the same people to complete all 4 questionnaires? Did you ask 4 people to each complete the same questionnaire? A lot more information is needed about the questionnaires and how you plan to relate them to each other.

Comment: yes all the 20 participants answered all the 4 questionnaires .

Comment: If you have all the same participants then just treat it all as one big questionaire and one dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new variable for each question asked in your questionnaire. You probably did this for your first questionnaire. You can add all the variables from your other questionnaires to the same spss-dataset.